# populate a combobox with an xml file

Tags: c#, xml

This is the XML file

```
<Users>
<User userID="4" username="lol" password="lol" usertype="Guest" />
</Users>
```

the code i tried

```
private void ExistingUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var xml = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "userID";

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load into a `DataSet` and use that as your the Combobox's `DataSource`:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("XMLFile1.xml"); 
this.comboBox1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "userID";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code Works perfectly. You need to mention the path for the xml document properly in the `doc.Load("path")`.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"D:\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\XMLFile1.xml");
        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("User");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["userID"].Value;
            dictionary.Add(Convert.ToInt32(attrVal), attrVal);
        }

        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionary, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
    }
```

Comment: im using xelement to load the file bc.